# SapUI5- ComboBox items binding with template, throws exception

Tags: data-binding, combobox, sapui5

I encounter an problem when trying to bind items of to a `sap.ui.ComboBox` (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.ComboBox.html) component.

At the moment, the process of binding items on the ComboBox component it's done like follows:

```
var itemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem();      //  creating a ListItem object                  
itemTemplate .bindProperty("text", ".........");   //  bind for the "text" property a certain path from the model



var comboBox = new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox({});    // create the ComboBox
comboBox .bindItems("........",itemTemplate);     // bind the items from a certain path, and provide as a template for the list the previously created one
```

Everything works as expected, except the fact that the following exception it's logged on the console:
"***A shared template must be marked with templateShareable:true in the binding info -***  "

While this seems suggestive, I still was not able to find when during binding should the "`templateShareable`" property set to "`true`".

Did anyone else encountered this issue? Am I doing something wrong when binding the items of a combobox?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template `Element` will be cloned for each item in the aggregation. So in your example you will get one clone of the `itemTemplate` ListItem for each item in the datasource.

A shared template is a template object that will be used by many controls. For example if you use your ComboBox as a template in a Table then the ComboBox will be cloned for each row. If your `itemTemplate` is marked as `templateShareable:true` then the template will not be cloned - all ComboBox clones will use the same `itemTemplate` object as template for their items.

You can specifiy the templateShareable as binding parameter:

```
comboBox.bindItems({ 
  path: "/items", 
  template: itemTemplate, 
  templateShareable:true
  });
```

If you don't specify templateShareable it will be assumed true *but* you will get the warning.

See [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/neforifeyi/1/edit?html,js,console,output): if you comment the `templateShareable:true` line you will get the warning in the console again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense.